# How to Apply SSL certificate on a IIS website using PowerShell or any script

Tags: ssl, iis

Need help to automation script/powershell to apply an existing SSL certificate on a IIS website.

Tried below step but not able to apply SSL on site.

1. Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My
2. New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
3. get-item cert:\LocalMachine\MY{GUID} | new-item 0.0.0.0!443

Appreciate your help if someone implemented it and can see applied SSL in IIS binding.

Tried below step but not able to apply SSL on site.

1. Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My
2. New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
3. get-item cert:\LocalMachine\MY{GUID} | new-item 0.0.0.0!443

Comment: Does this help? https://shellgeek.com/powershell-bind-certificate-to-iis-site/#:~:text=Create%20an%20SSL%20Binding%20Certificate%20for%20IIS%20Site,-Name%20%22HMITest%22%20-IP%20%22%2A%22%20-Port%20443%20-Protocol%20https

Answer (score 0):

I tried as following and works well.
[image]